# polling and timeout

Tags: c#, .net

I am polling a web service for a specific return value. (Using sync call since the web service returns right away). How to implement a timeout for this kind of polling, say 10 minutes and I will stop polling?

Comment: How are you polling? Can you post the code?

Comment: Would you mind starting a thread just before you call the web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest example I can think of is something like...

```
var service = new MyService();
var result = false;
var start = DateTime.Now;

while (!result && DateTime.Now < start.AddMinutes(10)) {
    result = service.Execute();
}
if (result){
    // Call successful
} else {
    // Routine timeout
}
```

But having more information would help.  You may then want to put a similar routine in another thread to prevent your application from locking up.

Answer (score 0):

Without anymore detail I can only offer you the following

[HttpWebRequest.Timeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx)

[WebRequest.Timeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx)